# Akka wait for stream completion

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'd like to know if it's possible to wait for completion of the following stream. It may be obvious for some people, but I'm new to akka.

```
final Materializer mat = ActorMaterializer.create(getContext());

String path = "Databases\\" + r.book.db + "\\" + r.book.title + ".txt";
Stream<String> fileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path));

Source<StreamResult, NotUsed> lines = Source.from(fileStream
                            .map(e -> new StreamResult(r.replyTo, e))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

lines.throttle(1, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                            .runWith(Sink.actorRef(sender, new StreamEnd()), mat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things which you need to pay attention here, is that you use `Sink` (that is the end of the stream definition) and [materialised values](https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/about-akka-streams/)

[`Sink.actorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Sink.html#actorRef(akka.actor.ActorRef,java.lang.Object)) returns `Sink<In,​NotUsed>`, so you can't just figure out stream termination information from what you have (because materialised value is `NotUsed` in your case). Moreover you can't use other sink which provides this info (eg, [`Sink.ignore`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Sink.html#ignore()), whose materialised value gives you `Future` about when stream finishes), because in general stream has one sink (of course, you can use [`Flow.alsoToMat`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOpsMat.html#alsoToMat(akka.stream.Graph,scala.Function2)), but there exists better approach)

You can use [`Flow.watchTermination`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/watchTermination.html) on the flow just before the last `Sink`, which will tell you about your upstream status. Probably it makes the most sense because you use `Sink.actorRef` in the shape of "send and forget".

I don't know your full use case, but just in case maybe you'll find [`Flow.ask`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Flow.html#ask(akka.actor.ActorRef,java.lang.Class,akka.util.Timeout)) useful. It sends a message to actor as well, but also waits for the actor response.